# Как при нажатии на ссылку присвоить класс всем похожим блокам?

Tags: jquery, классы, html, блок

Всем здравствуйте! Вопрос следующего характера. При нажатии на ссылку №2 #pp-2, блоку div с классом pp-2 присваивается дополнительный класс, т.е. блок окрашивается в цвет. Обратите, пожалуйста, внимание, что блок с классом pp-2 ни один. Так вот при нажатии на любой блок с классом pp-2 необходимо, чтобы не только этому блоку, на который нажал, но и всем блокам с похожим классом присваивался дополнительный класс, чтобы сразу все блоки с похожим классом окрашивались в цвет. Прошу помощи!

```
    <div class="pp-links">
        <div class="pp-1"><a href="#pp-1">1</a></div>
        <div class="pp-2"><a href="#pp-2">2</a></div>
        <div class="pp-3"><a href="#pp-3">Tab #3</a></div>
        <div class="pp-4"><a href="#pp-4">Tab #4</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pp-links">
        <div class="pp-1"><a href="#pp-1">1</a></div>
        <div class="pp-2_2 pp-2"><a href="#pp-2">2</a></div>
        <div class="pp-5"><a href="#pp-3">3</a></div>
        <div class="pp-6"><a href="#pp-4">Tab #4</a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="pp-content">
        <div id="pp-1" class="pp">
            <p>T1.2331223</p>
        </div>

        <div id="pp-2" class="pp">
            <p>T2.34345345</p>
        </div>

        <div id="pp-3" class="pp">
            <p>T3.454554</p>
        </div>

        <div id="pp-4" class="pp">
            <p>T4.565656</p>
        </div>
    </div>

.pp-links {
    position: absolute;
}
.pp-links div a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 22px;
    height: 12px;
}
.pp-links a:hover {
    background-color: #ffe972;
}
.pp-links div.active a, .pp-links div.active a:hover {
    background: #ffcd00;
}
.pp {
    display: none;
    background-color: #FAEEDD;
}
.pp.active {
    display: block;
}
.pp-1 a {top:1px;left:138px;}
.pp-2 a {top:416px;left:265px;}
.pp-3 a {top:284px;left:265px;}
.pp-4 a {top:305px;left:165px;}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.pp-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('.pp-content ' + currentAttrValue).fadeIn(500).siblings().hide();
        jQuery(this).parent('div').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - При нажатии берутся все блоки с class равные id блока

```
$(".pp").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  $("."+id).attr({"color":"red"});
});
```

2 - При нажатии берутся все блоки с class равные class блока

```
$(".pp").click(function() {
  var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(' ');
  for (var cl in classes)
    $("."+cl).attr({"color":"red"});
});
```

Поскольку у вас в вопросе непонятно что берем с блока id или класс

ЗЫ. попробуйте так

```
$('.pp-links a').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr("href").replace(/#/g, '.');
  $(href).css({"color":"red"});
});
```

Comment: "При нажатии на ссылку №2 #pp-2, блоку div с классом pp-2 присваивается дополнительный класс" и "любой блок с классом pp-2 необходимо, чтобы не только этому блоку, на..." непонятно брать id или class

Comment: Жутко извиняюсь, конечно же  `$(href).css({"color":"red"});` и в `<script></script>` заключите скрипт

Comment: Так. Смотрите что сделал я: Беру данные с `href` и меняю "#" на ".". Соответственно потом устанавливаю `color` в `red` у всех классов на которые ссылается `href`. Если вам надо устанавливать класс, то какой именно? Для добавления класса используйте `addClass`.

Comment: Дело в том, что ваш <a> перекрывает стиль текста. глянте что я сделал http://js.do/code/88104 всё работает

Comment: думаю для Вам надо по этому поводу создать другой вопрос. т.к. конструктивно он совершенно другой.